# AMDGPU-Pro drivers fail to install on Ubuntu 16.04, how to fix it?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, apt, amdgpu-pro

I'm trying to install the AMDGPU-pro drivers on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but it fails with the same error regardless of the version I try.

I am running Ubuntu from a live persistent USB that seems otherwise to be running correctly.

I updated my system (added universe, apt update, apt upgrade), rebooted.

I downloaded the drivers from AMD's website, decompressed and attempted the install as suggested in the docs here:

https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx#

By running:

`./amdgpu-pro-install`

It always fails with:

```
...
Reading package lists... Done                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu-pro-amdgpu1:i386 (= 1:2.4.82-492261)
                    Depends: libgbm1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 17.40-492261)
                    Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx:i386 (= 17.40-492261)
                    Depends: libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri:i386 (= 17.40-492261)
                    Depends: libegl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 17.40-492261)
                    Depends: libgles2-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 17.40-492261)
                    Depends: vulkan-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 17.40-492261)
                    Depends: libvdpau-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 1:17.0.1-492261)
                    Depends: libopencl1-amdgpu-pro:i386 (= 17.40-492261)
                    Depends: opencl-amdgpu-pro-icd:i386 (= 17.40-492261)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried versions 16.5, 16.4 and 17.4, all with the same failure.

I rebuilt the usb drive, etc, no changes... regardless of whether I update the system or not.

How can I fix this so that the drivers will install?

Comment: FWIW I tried AMDGPU-Pro and found it no better (tested with glmark2) than AMDGPU. I also tested the 3 main bleeding-edge/fast-update repos for video drivers (ie oibaf, pkppa and one other) they didn't give much difference, barely noticeable, and when I had problems fell back to the open source standard one `xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu` which is sufficient for me (I play CSGO/Robocraft/a few other games).

Comment: The issue is that i need to run another package that requires amdgpu-pro... so im stuck with having to get this one installed...

Comment: It says you've held broken packages what's `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep -i held` tell you that you have held? [I'm guessing it's lying!] Have you worked through the list and tried to install each of those dependencies by themselves? Eg `sudo apt install libdrm-amdgpu-pro-amdgpu1:i386`. Does `sudo aptitude` then press `b` show you any broken packages? Also it would be useful to add to the question the package that you need `amdgpu-pro` for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try adding the i386 architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Then try the setup again.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this helped:

> If you experience issues [5] with a AMD R9 390 series graphics card,
>   set `radeon.cik_support=0 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1
>   amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.dpm=1 amdgpu.dc=1` as kernel parameters to
>   force the use of amdgpu driver instead of radeon.
>
> If it still does not work, try disabling DPM, by setting the kernel
>   parameters to: `radeon.cik_support=0 radeon.si_support=0
>   amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.si_support=1`

Source:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU#R9_390_series_poor_performance_and/or_instability